# Como saber quais teclas são apertadas em C# ConsoleApp e definir eventos

Tags: c#, console

Como posso "ler" qual tecla é apertada e definir um evento para tal tecla caso seja apertada.
Exemplo: se apertar F1 Soma, F2 subtrai e por ai vai
Encontrei no site de ajuda do C# este exemplo, mas não entendi como ele funciona:

```
    using System;

class Example 
{
   public static void Main() 
   {
      ConsoleKeyInfo cki;
      // Prevent example from ending if CTL+C is pressed.
      Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;

      Console.WriteLine("Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.");
      Console.WriteLine("Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit: \n");
      do {
         cki = Console.ReadKey(true);
         Console.Write("You pressed ");
         if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Alt) != 0) Console.Write("ALT+");
         if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Shift) != 0) Console.Write("SHIFT+");
         if ((cki.Modifiers & ConsoleModifiers.Control) != 0) Console.Write("CTL+");
         Console.WriteLine("{0} (character '{1}')", cki.Key, cki.KeyChar);
      } while (cki.Key != ConsoleKey.Escape);
   }
}
```

Mas este código apenas imprime as teclas apertadas

```
// This example displays output similar to the following:
//       Press any combination of CTL, ALT, and SHIFT, and a console key.
//       Press the Escape (Esc) key to quit:
//       
//       You pressed CTL+A (character '☺')
//       You pressed C (character 'c')
//       You pressed CTL+C (character '♥')
//       You pressed K (character 'k')
//       You pressed ALT+I (character 'i')
//       You pressed ALT+U (character 'u')
//       You pressed ALT+SHIFT+H (character 'H')
//       You pressed Escape (character '←')
```

Agradeço pela ajuda

Comment: Tente usar isso: Console.ReadKey(true).Key == ConsoleKey.F1; //isso irá comparar se o caracter digitado é igual a F1

Comment: Isso funcionou.

Answer (score 3):

Basicamente você pode utilizar a classe `ConsoleKeyInfo` para obter as teclas pressionadas, veja abaixo um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ExemploKey
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ConsoleKeyInfo key;

            do
            {
                key = Console.ReadKey();
                Console.WriteLine(key.Key + " foi pressionada.");

            } while (key.Key != ConsoleKey.X);
        }
    }
}
```

Neste caso a aplicação vai exibir no console todas as teclas que você pressionar menos a tecla `X`, quando a tecla `X` for pressionada o programa será encerrado. Para verificar as teclas funcionais basta seleciona-las através da enumeração `ConsoleKey`, veja mais alguns exemplos:

```
ConsoleKey.F1;
ConsoleKey.F10;
ConsoleKey.F13;
```

Esta `enum` possui todas as teclas que serão utilizadas por você.

Fontes:
[ConsoleKeyInfo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.consolekeyinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
[ConsoleKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.consolekey%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
[how to handle key press event in console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898182/how-to-handle-key-press-event-in-console-application).